# DATEDIFF() Between dates with different ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   START_DATE
  ,ID
  ,USER
  ,ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY START_DATE) AS RN

FROM TABLE
```

Which brings the following results:

```
START_DATE   ID   USER   RN
2019-01-01   200  01     1
2019-01-10   450  01     2
2019-01-02   500  02     1
```

I'd like to just show users who have more than one Start Date (row number 1, 2, 3) and exclude users who just have a `row_number` of `1`. Second, I need to show the `DATEDIFF()` between each `Row_Number`.

I thought to include `ROW_NUMBER` as a way to do this, but didn't know where to go past that. It might need a new solution. A sample of what that would look like is:

```
START_DATE  USER   datediff
2019-01-01  01     10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH TMP AS (
    SELECT 
       START_DATE
      ,ID
      ,USER
      ,LAG(START_DATE) OVER ( PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY START_DATE) AS LAST_START_DATE
      ,CASE WHEN MIN(START_DATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY USER ) = 
                 MAX(START_DATE) OVER ( PARTITION BY USER) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END ExcludeIfOnlyNonUnique
      FROM TEST_DATA)
SELECT TMP.START_DATE,
       TMP.ID,
       TMP.USER,
       DATEDIFF(TMP.START_DATE, TMP.LAST_START_DATE) START_DATE_DIFF
  FROM TMP
 WHERE ExcludeIfOnlyNonUnique = 0;
```

Comment: "Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause."

Comment: @PhilK Bummer. I'm used to Oracle lately. Is the distinct necessary - do you want the records excluded if there are 2 records but they have the same start_date?

Comment: @PhilK Added alternative

Comment: I guess it's not taking the MIN() and MAX() now... But, also, there could be more than 2 row numbers (ie. 3, 4...)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this but one of the more elegant would be using the Microsoft SQL Server functions lead and lag.  These functions allow you to access values from preceding and following rows in partition over approaches.  Read up on them here:

Lead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Lag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the resource!

Comment: Yeah, they are some of those hidden goodies buried in the TSQL language!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CTE and join to the query twice.

```
WITH MY_QUERY AS (
  SELECT 
    START_DATE, 
    ID, 
    USER,
    ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY START_DATE) AS RN
  FROM SOMETABLE
), MY_ID AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT USER FROM MY_QUERY
)
SELECT Q1.START_DATE, Q1.USER, DATEDIFF(Q1.START_DATE, Q2.START_DATE) AS DIFF
FROM MY_ID ID
JOIN MY_QUERY Q1 ON ID.USER = Q1.USER AND Q1.RN = 1
JOIN MY_QUERY Q2 ON ID.USER = Q2.USER AND Q2.RN = 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not yield any results

Comment: @PhilK well it has inner joins.  did you make a typo?

Comment: you were right, I had a typo. I included a `dd` for the DATEDIFF and edited the Join's. However, I failed to mention in my example that there could be more than 1 row, there could be 3, 4, 5, (in some cases).

Comment: @phil I just ignore those -- what was the business rule you wanted to use?

Answer (score 0):

try this below script-

```
WITH CTE(START_DATE, ID, [USER], RN)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    START_DATE
    ,ID
    ,USER
    ,ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY START_DATE) AS RN
)

SELECT MIN(START_DATE) [START_DATE], 
[USER],
DATEDIFF(DD,MIN(START_DATE),MAX(START_DATE))+1 [datediff]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [USER]
HAVING MAX(RN) > 1
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this doesn't really do what the question was asking if there are more than two records for the user.

Comment: This did not address if there are more than 2 row_numbers (ie. 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `row_number()`.  You want `count()`:

```
select t.*
from (select . . . ,
             count(*) over (partition by user) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

You can include `row_number()` in the result set, of course, if that is still needed.

Comment: This did not address the datediff() part of the question